# What is the difference between WAF and security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I Would like to understand what is the difference between WAF, Security Group, and a routing table.
Let's say I have a VPC, 2 subnets (a private one) and I want to deploy a web application (UI and backend service and a database (RDS)), In this scenario where does WAF and security groups come into the picture.
Can someone help me to understand a use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP protocol is built on top of the TCP protocol.

WAF inspects the HTTP traffic before it reaches your web application in order to block malicious web traffic.
In order to implement WAF in front of a containerized application (running on ECS for example) or in front of an application running on EC2 you should use an Application Load Balancer in front of the application servers and associate the WAF with that load balancer.
If your application runs on Lambda you can do the same but using API Gateway.

A Security Group accepts or blocks networking protocols such as TCP, UDP, ICMP - based on ports. Open up port 443 and 80 if you want to expose your web application.

Routing tables should be associated with your subnets so that the network traffic (TCP) can knows where to go.

Best practice is to put your application servers and databases in private subnets (with routing tables that does not route traffic from the Internet) and then put e.g Application Load Balancer in the public subnets in order to accept traffic from the Internet and route it to your private subnets.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for sharing your knowledge.